# Dialog get closed if any event occurs inside it in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually i am having a grid(home) in a page,if the user clicks the link inside the grid(home),it will show a dialog with another grid-("detailsgrid" with edit,update and cancel options).
Now the Problem is,

The dialog shows the grid(detailsgrid),but if i click edit button it get closed.after clicking the link again, the dialog shows the grid in edit mode.

if i change the text in textbox inside the grid(detailsgrid),again it get closed.

The detailsgrid_onRowUpdating event not fired

And i designed these two grids in different div controls. if i put this in same div control(both grid will show one by one not in dialog) it works fine.

My code

```
function ShowDialog(subtitle) {
       $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            hide: "puff",
            show: "slide",
            width: "70%",
            title: subtitle,
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").find("form").remove();
                $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');

            }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    }
```

Then, i am binding the detailsgrid in homegrid_RowCommand.

Homegrid_RowCommand

```
protected void HomesGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewRow row = HomeGrid.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
            if (row != null)
            {
                var username = row.Cells[1].Text;
                if (e.CommandName == "Details")
                {
                    DetailsGrid.Visible = true;
                    DetailsGrid.DataSource = page2.GetDetails(username);
        DetailsGrid.DataBind();
                    DetailsGrid.Visible = true;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "javascript:ShowDialog(" + "'Details Of " + username + "');", true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

DetailsGrid_RowCommand

```
protected void DetailsGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: are you using bootstrap dialog?

Comment: Sounds like you encounter the `postback` problem, just a blind guess, but worth to check it

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap dialog

Comment: can you show us your both of row_command and aspx code.?

Comment: @Chirag i updated my question with the Row_command